# building the kernel for biackfin target

Tags: buildroot

I'm trying to build a rootfs for an blackfin target, However I can't figure out how I configure the kernel that buildroot produces. The first run through came up with menuconfig, but it's cached the .config since then and I can't see where to change it.

regards
santhosh babu

Answer (score 1):

You need to run `make linux-menuconfig` to ask Buildroot to start the `menuconfig` interface of the Linux kernel.